# Unknown AMF type & other errors when transfering files from flash to java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, blazeds, amf

I'm using a Flash tool to transfer data to Java. I'm having problems when it comes to sending multiple objects at once. The objects being sent are just generic Object objects, so it's not a case of needed to register a class alias or anything.

Sending one object works fine. Once I start sending multiple objects (putting the same Objects in an Array and sending that), it starts getting weird. Up to three objects in an Array seems to work fine. More than that I get different errors in the `readObject()` function, such as:

- Unknown AMF type '47'
- Unknown AMF type '40'
- Unknown AMF type '20'
- OutOfBoundsExceptions index 23, size 0
- NullPointerException
- etc.

Sending 3 objects will work, sending 4 gives me the error. If I delete one of the previous 3 that worked (while keeping the fourth that was added), it'll work again. Anyone know what's going on?

Some more info:

- Communication goes through a Socket class on the Flash side. This is pure AS3, no flex.
- Messages are compressed before being sent and decompressed on the server, so I'm pretty sure it's not a buffer size issue (unless I'm missing something)
- BlazeDS version seems to be 4.0.0.14931 on the jar
- Flash version is 10.1 (it's an AIR app)

**Update with rough code**

Examples of the objects being sent:

```
var o:Object    = { };
o._key          = this._key.toString();
o.someParam     = someString;
o.someParam2    = someInt;
o.someParam3    = [someString1, someString2, someString3];
...
```

It's added to our event object (which we use to determine the event to call, the data etc to pass). The event object is been registered as a class alias

That object is sent to the server through a Socket like so:

```
myByteArray.writeObject( eventObj );
myByteArray.compress();
mySocket.writeBytes( myByteArray );
mySocket.flush();
```

On the server side, we receive the bytes, and decompress them. We create a Amf3Input object and set the input stream, then read it:

```
Amf3Input amf3Input = new Amf3Input( mySerializationContext );
amf3Input.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( buffer ) ); // buffer is a byte[]
MyEventObj eventObj = (MyEventObj)amf3Input.readObject(); // MyEventObj is the server version of the client event object
```

If it's going to crash with an "unknown AMF type error", it does so immediately i.e. when we try to read the object, and not when it's trying to read a subobject.

In stepping through the read code, it seems when I pass an array of objects, if the length is <= 4, it reads the length right. If the length is bigger than that, it reads it's length as 4.

Comment: It's very hard to have an idea without seeing the code.

Comment: I've added some rough code - it's a bit hard to take out the relevant bits without posting a huge source dump (which I can't do anyway). There's nothing special going on. Plus it works when sending single objects, or small arrays of objects. Go above 3 and it goes crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. Basically messages are compressed before being sent and decompressed on the server. What I didn't see was that the `byte[]` buffer that the message was being decompressed to was always 1024 length, which was fine for small arrays of objects. Once that was passed however, it would overwrite the buffer (I'm not quite sure what happens in Java when you try to write more bytes than are available - whether it loops back around, or shifts the data).

When it came to reading the amf object, the first thing it does it read an int, and uses this to determine what type of object it's trying to decode. As this int was gibberish (47, 110, -10), it was failing.

Time to start prepending message lengths I think :)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting AMF deserialization errors, there are several possible issues that could be contributing to the problem. Here are several techniques for doing further diagnostics:

1. Use a network traffic sniffer to make sure that what you are sending matches what you are receiving. On the Mac I'll use [CocoaPacketAnalyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/), or you can try [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), which can actually decode AMF packets that it notices.
2. Feed the data to a different AMF library, like [PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/) or [RocketAMF](https://github.com/rubyamf/rocketamf) to see if it's a problem with BlazeDS or with how you're calling it. It's also possible that you may get a different error message that will give you a better idea of where it's failing.
3. Check the format of the AMF packet. AMF server calls have some additional wrapping around them that would throw off a deserializer if it's not expecting to encounter that wrapping, and vice versa for purely serialized objects. Server call packets always start off with a `0x00`, followed by the AMF version (`0x00`, `0x03`, or in rare cases `0x02`).

Comment: thanks for the hints. to answer some of your points: 1) downloaded charles. i'll see if it gives me any hints. 2) I can't really plug in another amf library with rewriting a lot of stuff. Also, I'm only debugging this - this isn't my code :D 3) This is going from client to server. So far I've had no problems with server to client. Also, it works fine sending multiple items up until a certain point. Then it goes crazy with a different error each time

Comment: not really familar with how charles works. do i need to do something specific to get it to listen to the traffic? it catches the AIR auto-update XML file that I have, but not the traffic between the app and the server. The app is AIR based and the server is local on my computer (for testing)